# Uploading file in .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using fineuploader to upload a file. everything works fine for files under 200MB. everything over just fails. A new file is created but it's empty (meaning 0kb)

already modified my web.config to allow for up to 500mb uploads. but doesn't seem to help.

**web.config:**

```
  <security>
      <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
      </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

and

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="512000" executionTimeout="900" requestLengthDiskThreshold="512000" />
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(string qqfile)
{
    try
    {
        Stream stream = Request.Files.Count > 0 ? Request.Files[0].InputStream : Request.InputStream;

        string filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\100", qqfile);
        using (Stream file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(file);
        }
....
```

Why can't I upload files over 200MB?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1646283.aspx/1 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6472631/1182982 may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:
It was a web.config settings:

web.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="90" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
```

and

```
 <system.webServer>
      <security>
          <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
          </requestFiltering>
      </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Thanks Yasser for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that springs to mind is a limitation in IIS. Before "Integrated Mode" in IIS7 one had to deal with the IIS-MetaBase for setting IIS-properties.

If you're running your website in "Integrated Mode" or using the VS Development Webserver (Cassini-based) it might work, if you're running production in "Classic Mode" it will not use the integrated-configuration and fall back to the metabase. If it does and you haven't edited the metabase then any upload over the default metabase-upload-limit will fail.

From your code/config/question I can't determine what mode the website you're having problems with is running - which might be vital to answer your question - so please supply these details.