# How can I get the IIS upload limit using PHP?

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I want make a check against the IIS upload limit of the server my PHP script is running in the same manner as `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` works for the PHP settings.

I'm thinking about parsing the `web.config` file to get the value of `maxAllowedContentLength`, but I was wondering if there is a standard way to ask the webserver directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one link telling a bit about other configuration setting you should read [Which gets priority, maxRequestLength or maxAllowedContentLength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327452/which-gets-priority-maxrequestlength-or-maxallowedcontentlength)  **And i dont think there is other way as to read the ini file (php have simple ini file reader).**
I could propose using some library that splits files like `plupload` - it can split your files to smaller pieces, upload each piece and then recombine it into one big file bypassing the server maximum upload file / body limits.

Comment: You can try `phpinfo();` if the configuration of iis is given to php it will be there - if not i would read the file.