# maxRequestLength for .Net 4.5.1 framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to convert a .Net framework 4.0 code into .Net framework 4.5. This is basically a **file upload related** code. Now I face some problems. What is the maximum value of maxRequestLength? 
I already add this line in my **web.config file** but it does not work and the Error code is **0x800700b7**

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout ="3600" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
  </namespaces>
  </pages>
  <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>

   <security>  
  <requestFiltering>  
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />  
  </requestFiltering>  
  </security> 

<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are hosted in IIS, you need two settings:

- **maxRequestLength** - for ASP.net (measured in KB)
- **maxAllowedContentLength** - for IIS (measured in Bytes)

Sample config: (this is for 100MB upload limit)

```
<configuration>  
    <system.web>  
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" />  
    </system.web>  
    <system.webServer>  
        <security>  
            <requestFiltering>  
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />  
            </requestFiltering>  
        </security>  
    </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

The smaller of the two will take precedence. For IIS, the default is 4MB.

**Error handling**

Both throws different exceptions.

- `maxRequestLength` - Whenever a file exceeds this setting, you'll get an Application_Error (standard ASP error)
- `maxAllowedContentLength` - Whenever a file exceeds this setting, you'll get IIS error.

The IIS error is harder to debug, so it is advisable that you set the `maxAllowedContentLength` larger. `maxRequestLength` is easier to catch since its at application level.

**Sources:**

- http://forums.iis.net/t/1169846.aspx
- [Which gets priority, maxRequestLength or maxAllowedContentLength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327452)

Comment: The <system.webServer /> setting must be inside the <configuration />.