# System.web setting for httpRuntime Element

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to upload a file, here is my setting

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true"  />
<httpRuntime  executionTimeout="110"
 maxRequestLength="4096"
 requestLengthDiskThreshold="256"
 useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
 minFreeThreads="8"
 minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
 appRequestQueueLimit="5000"
 enableKernelOutputCache="true"
 enableVersionHeader="true"
 requireRootedSaveAsPath="true"
 enable="true"
 shutdownTimeout="90"
 delayNotificationTimeout="5"
 waitChangeNotification="0"
 maxWaitChangeNotification="0"
 enableHeaderChecking="true"
 sendCacheControlHeader="true"
 apartmentThreading="false"
/></system.web>
```

Here I set maxRequestLength to 4MB, but I am able to upload up to 500kb only.
I have tried with multiple settings but couldn't get any solution.
Where should i chage to make it work ?

Comment: [link] [Check it here..this may help you out.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RCA: When I was uploading a file, after some time I was doing a location.realod() to get the latest data.
It was working fine with up to 500kb file because in that time this much file size was getting uploaded, but If size is bigger It was taking time and before It succeeds location.realod() was getting called.

```
Solved: used callback and instead of loading full page, just call the getAll method.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41118265/1498669 which describes two parameters (IIS and WCF) in detail (one in KiloBytes and the other in Bytes).