# ASP.NET Connection Unexpectedly Closed on >2MB Image File Processing

Tags: asp.net, image-processing

I have the following code:

```
var myImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
```

As soon as my application hits this line of code, it throws the following exception:

```
  System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: 
           The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

Note that my application is on a shared host and exception is only thrown on images files greater than 2MB.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the response time in the web config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="4096"
    useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
    minFreeThreads="8"
    minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
    appRequestQueueLimit="100" />
 </system.web>
... 
</configuration>
```

For more information, please, see [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(vs.71).aspx).

[How to increase time in web.config for executing sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976737/how-to-increse-time-in-webconfig-for-executing-query)

Comment: <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1073741824" /> is what I currently have

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I have `debug=true` in the `web.config` file which would overwrite the `executionTimeout` value to system default.