# ASP.NET Site crashes when uploading "large" files

Tags: asp.net, upload

I've got the Fileupload and I set this in my WebConfig:

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime
 executionTimeout="110"
 maxRequestLength="102400"
 requestLengthDiskThreshold="80"
 useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
 minFreeThreads="8"
 minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
 appRequestQueueLimit="5000"
 enableKernelOutputCache="true"
 enableVersionHeader="true"
 requireRootedSaveAsPath="true"
 enable="true"
 shutdownTimeout="90"
 delayNotificationTimeout="5"
 waitChangeNotification="0"
 maxWaitChangeNotification="0"
 enableHeaderChecking="true"
 sendCacheControlHeader="true"
 apartmentThreading="false" />
  </system.web>
```

that allows me, to upload 100MB files.. `maxRequestLength="102400"`

Now the problem is, that the site crashes, when uploading b.E a 85MB File..
It stops working on about 70% and I get an Error.. How can I solve this Problem?

Comment: Well unfortunately, I don't get an error, sorry

Comment: An error yes, "The site stopped working, look if its a valid site, if u are online with proxy try this and this and and".. the usual error..

Comment: Gone through scenario again, it takes about 2minutes, then Firefox shows this error: Error: Disconnected , The connection to the server was reset while the page is loaded... And @musefan: Thank you for your constructive responses >.<

Comment: Check my answer, seems like the circa 2 minutes is related to the 110 seconds executionTimeout

Comment: Check for executiontimeout value. see the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804622/how-to-upload-content-more-than-2-mbs-on-website-created-using-asp-net-4-0/7804670#7804670

Comment: I updated executiontimeout to a higher value and its still not working :(

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked if the executionTimeout="110" is causing the issue? If you upload the file multiple times, will it fail at almost the same time? Try updating the executionTimeout to a higher value.

Comment: I don't really have a Progressbar, but it might be always at the same time.. I will try increase the value..

Comment: @eMi: Do you have a watch, clock, the ability to count? that should help, also 110 seems a strange timeout number to me, did you choose that for a reason?

Comment: @musefan 110 seconds is the default executionTimeout. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx)

Comment: @ChristiaanV: I had a feeling that might be the case, wasn't sure though, seem strange number to me - perhaps I will seek out a reason