# HttpPostedFileBase status in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

An asp.net mvc action takes an HttpPostedFileBase parameter:

```
public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    //Q1: at the start of this action method, what's the status of this file? 
    //UploadCompleted or Uploading or something else?

    //Q2: where is the file stored? memory or a temp file?

    if (answer of Q1 is Uploading)
    {
        //Q3a: what happens if file.SaveAs is invoked? 
        //block the current thread until the file is uploaded?
    }
    else if (answer if Q1 is UploadCompleted)
    {
        //Q3b: which means the developer can do nothing before the file is uploaded?
        //if the business logic limits the size of the file(e.g. <= 5MB), how can we
        //prevent evil-intended uploading?
    }
}
```

Q4 here: I want to record the total time of this request, when the user begins to upload the file, the timer starts.when the user finished uploading the file(or my `Save` action is completed), the timer ends. How can I know when the user begins to upload?

Answer (score 1):

First, have a look a this question for the basics : [File Upload ASP.NET MVC 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0)

Q1 : The action is called once the file is fully available.

Q2 : From msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx

> The amount of data that is buffered in server memory for a request,
>   which includes file uploads, can be specified by accessing the
>   RequestLengthDiskThreshold property or by setting the
>   requestLengthDiskThreshold attribute of the httpRuntime Element
>   (ASP.NET Settings Schema) element within the Machine.config or
>   Web.config file.

Q3 : You can specify max upload size in web.config : [How to increase the max upload file size in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net)

Comment: Brilliant answer! What about Question 4?