# Uploading Multiple Files - MVC..is there a total file size limit?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-file-upload

I have a form from which users can add a property listing. Apart from the data that the user has to enter, the user can also upload a number of images. I'm using the HTML5 multiple attribute to allow users to upload more than one file at once.

For some reason the HttpPost Add method I have always fires when I upload one image. However, when I try to upload multiple images the method does not fire. Up till now I'm not getting any errors so I'm not sure what is wrong with my implementation.

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProperty", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Property</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Title
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="text" name="title" />
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Description
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="text" name="desc" />
        </div>

        @* ... more input fields... *@

        <div class="editor-label">
            Images
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file" />
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProperty(FormCollection form, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
{
    Property p = new Property();
    p.Title = form["title"];
    p.Description = form["desc"];

    // ... setting Property fields

    new PropertiesBL().AddProperty(p);

    for (int i = 0; i < file.Count(); i++)
    {
        // ... loop and save uploaded file(s)
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT - Further testing**

To test the file upload I've created a new view with just a form containing a file uploader. I've tried uploading different file types. What I've noted is that when uploading for example 10 documents the Upload method fired. But when trying to upload 3 (large) images it didn't fire. I'm thinking that there's some kind of limit with regards to the total number of bytes being uploaded...I'm not sure if this makes sense though.

*Simple Test*

```
<form method="post" action="/Test/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="images" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I've also tried uploading multiple files separately. When I try to upload 3 large images (each image about 2 MB) the method did not fire. I'm almost certain that this is an issue related to some kind of total maximum file size.

```
<form method="post" action="/Test/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image_1" />
    <input type="file" name="image_2" />
    <input type="file" name="image_3" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with the maximum number of bytes that one can upload. This can be changed by setting the `maxRequestLength` in the web.config file.

**Reference**

[How to upload large files using MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287706/how-to-upload-large-files-using-mvc-4-plupload)

**Code:**

```
<system.web>

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" 
        maxRequestLength="2147483647"
        executionTimeout="1600" 
        requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
   ....

</system.web>
```

The answer for the linked question, lists the following under the `<system.web>` tag however I could only add it in the `<system.webServer>` tag:

```
<system.webServer>

    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    ....

</system.webServer>
```