# How to fix multiple file upload maximum path length limitation in ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My file upload is **working fine with City 3** but for other cities it's not.  
I followed the advice in this [site](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/upload-large-files-asp-net-radasyncupload) in editing the `web.config` 
but, I don't have luck to do it right. What I am missing?

**Tested CSV Files**
City 1 CSV => doesn't work with normal browser but works on [chromium](https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/) 
484 Files  
9.40 MB

City 2 CSV => doesn't work with normal browser but works on [chromium](https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/)  
824 Files  
31.7 MB  
**City 3 CSV => uploading and working**  
396 Files  
10.7 MB

A single csv file is between maximum 150KB and mininum 1KB  
Filename sample: `City1-Fixed-FC6947BDF3AA-GTW_FC6947BDF3AA_OMS_RDS_20190127_110000.csv`

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>    
    <add name="W0rldEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=XXXXXXX;user id=sa;password=101010;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=XXXXXXX; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa; Password=101010" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

**Model**

```
public class FileModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select file.")]
    [Display(Name = "Browse File")]
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model WaterW0rld.Models.FileModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UploadFiles";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Meter Readings</h4>
            <small class="card-subtitle"> Upload meter readings data. </small>
            <div class="tab-content br-n pn">                  
                @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "MeterReading", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <hr />
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.files, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.files, "", new { @type = "file", @multiple = "multiple" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.files, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                @*TODO: Add notification while uploading *@
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-success">
                                @ViewBag.UploadStatus
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
        var dt = new DataTable();
            string hashes;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {   
                var tasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    //Checking file is available to save.  
                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        var InputFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var ServerSavePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/MeterReadings/") + InputFileName);

                        file.SaveAs(ServerSavePath);

                        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/MeterReadings/"), InputFileName);

                        if (!file.FileName.Contains("GTW_RAW"))
                        {                           
                            if (_pgf.GetGatewayLogDuplicate(path) == 0)
                            {
                                hashes = _pgf.GetHashes(path, path);                                                             
                                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => _meterReadings.BulkInsertToDB(path, hashes)));
                            }
                        }
                        ViewBag.UploadStatus = files.Count().ToString() + " files uploaded successfully.";
                    }
                }
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

I want to upload all files regardless of how many it was as long as files size is in range of `100MB` any workaround is welcome.

Comment: Define `doesn't work`. Look at the response the server is generating. What status code is it? What payload?

Comment: Use a tool which can capture request and response during file upload, you should get response contents. Related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038390/uploading-multiple-files-mvc-is-there-a-total-file-size-limit.

Comment: @mjwills sorry, I find culprit using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851751/what-is-the-max-number-of-files-to-select-in-an-html5-multiple-file-input) I have issue with file path ex. `City1-Fixed-FC6947BDF3AA-GTW_FC6947BDF3AA_OMS_RDS_20190127_110000.csv`  when combine with other filename it consume max limitation length path of chrome browser. do you have workaround for this?

Comment: I am 100% sure also that there is no status code or payload response from server. In client side alone when you reach the limit File name area of file upload blank out.

Comment: _doesn't work means  doesn't upload_; _status code = none_; _payload = none_

Comment: @mjwills how about this, just recreate my codes and then test it with filename style `City1-Fixed-FC6947BDF3AA-GTW_FC6947BDF3AA_OMS_RDS_20190127_110000_x.csv` make it 500 csv so we can understand each other.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the issue is about the filename when you upload large amount of files with this kind of filename `City1-Fixed-FC6947BDF3AA-GTW_FC6947BDF3AA_OMS_RDS_20190127_110000.csv` it exceed the normal browser allowed characters.