# Unable to upload files if size is more than 4mb in asp.net mvc3

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am unable to ulpoad files if total size of files is more than 4mb in asp.net mvc3.
I am using jquery.form.js to upload file and uses ajax to post the form to server side. It works fine if total size of files uploaded is less than 4 mb but if exceeds 4mb then its not posting the form to server side...
My application's web.config is already configured to 1GB using maxRequestLength attribute of httpruntime tag.

Can anyone knows how to allow application to post larger files?
Thanks

Comment: duplicated from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16294635/1233788 . please search a little before ask your question to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to  increase the [maxRequestLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=VS.100).aspx) setting in web.config.

Something like

```
maxRequestLength="8192" for 8MB
```

By default the machine.config is configured with 4MB and is reflected in all the places. So you need to increase it.