# Calculating helping columns on R script on azure machine learning, so they could be later added to tabular model

Tags: r, .net, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service

So I am creating flow for imorting data, so some aggragate columns could be uploaded to Azure Sql database and later on tabular model. Now I would to describe the flow, so someone could tell about it, pros and cons.

### At this stage of development the flow is:

#### 1.

User imports CSV file to my web service  (in ASP.NET CORE 2.1) to Azure Sql database, for importing I am using Sql Bulk Library in .NET Core.
The webservice and database will be located on the server in azure.
Some of the data importstakes about 20minutes.

#### 2.

When the data import is finished, I am calling Azure Machine Learning Web service, who will calculate helping columns so later on with MDX queries I could retrieve data from tabular model more easily and more efficiently. These helping columns will tell if users were active previous month or not for example.

#### 3.

When R script finishes calculation it updates Azure Sql Database table with new column(s).

#### 4.

When columns are updated in a database, I am telling Azure Analysis Service to refresh database(not in .net core version because it doesn't support ADOM.NET) So I am created another web service (.NET 4.7) so I could from web service automatically refresh it.

#### 5.

So finally the new data appears on a tabular model so I can get information of data using MDX queries with ADOM.NET library.

Please tell me if there is a better solution for this flow.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database supports in memory R execution for feature engineering, training models and inference.  It is currently in preview, but will GA soon: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-machine-learning-services-overview

Also at //BUILD, Microsoft announced a serverless performance profile for Azure SQL DB which is perfect for low frequency jobs like this.

This hopefully can simplify your workflow dramatically.