# what can do when a file is not uploading greater than 12 mb?

Tags: asp.net

When I'm uploading file. file greater than 12mb is not uploading and session getting expired while do it

```
protected void populateCategoryList()
{
    try
    {
        string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mcqConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_MCQ_GetCategories", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@type", "Video"));
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        conn.Close();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "CategoryList");

        lbCategory.Controls.Clear();
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTable result = ds.Tables[0];
            if (result.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow odrMain = result.Rows[i];
                    if (odrMain["parent_cat"].ToString().Trim() == "0" || odrMain["parent_cat"].ToString().Trim() == "")
                    {
                        lbCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem(odrMain["name"].ToString(), odrMain["id"].ToString()));

                        for (int k = 0; k < result.Rows.Count; k++)
                        {
                            DataRow odr = result.Rows[k];
                            if (odr["parent_cat"].ToString().Trim() == odrMain["id"].ToString().Trim())
                            {
                                lbCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem("\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0" + odr["name"].ToString(), odr["id"].ToString()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //exception handling
    }
}

protected void createMedia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string rootPath = Server.MapPath("~/videos/");
    if (FileUploadVideos.FileName.Contains(".mp4") || FileUploadVideos.FileName.Contains(".MP4") || FileUploadVideos.FileName.Contains(".mp3") || FileUploadVideos.FileName.Contains(".MP3"))
    {
        string selectedCategories = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < lbCategory.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lbCategory.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                selectedCategories += lbCategory.Items[i].Value + ",";
            }
        }
        int[] status = new int[2];
        status = SQLHelper.createVideo(tbTitle.Text.Trim(), selectedCategories, Path.GetExtension(FileUploadVideos.FileName), Path.GetExtension(FileUploadPoster.FileName));

        if (status[0] == 1)
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = "Media added sucessfully. Use above form to add another Video/Podcast";
            FileUploadVideos.SaveAs(rootPath + status[1].ToString() + Path.GetExtension(FileUploadVideos.FileName));
            if (FileUploadPoster.HasFile)
            {
                FileUploadPoster.SaveAs(rootPath + status[1].ToString() + Path.GetExtension(FileUploadPoster.FileName));
            }

            emptyFields();
        }
        else if (status[0] == -1)
            ErrorMessage.Text = "Media already exists. Please try some other Title";
        else
            ErrorMessage.Text = "Some error occured. Please try again. If problem persists conatct your administrator";
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMessage.Text = "Only MP4 media is allowed to upload.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure your settings in the web.config are ok? The maxrequestlength is the file size in KB and the execution time out is how long before it times out, in seconds.

```
<httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="90240" executionTimeout="420"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net).

Try adjusting the maxRequestLength in your web.config.

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="[number in KB]" />
  </system.web>
```