# Restrict the size of file upload in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, filesize

I want to restrict my file size upload to a certain limit. But, the problem here is that I want to provide a popup alert when the upload size is exceeded . But , instead the web page here shows the following error

```
HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found
```

`The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.`
Here's my code

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fuDocpath.HasFiles)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            lbldateStamp.Text = now.ToString("mm_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");
            //string foldername = lblsessionID.Text + "_" + lbldateStamp.Text;
            string folderpath = (Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded_Files/") + lblsessionID.Text + "_" + lbldateStamp.Text + "/");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
            if (fuDocpath.PostedFile.ContentLength < 20970000)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (HttpPostedFile files in fuDocpath.PostedFiles)
                    {
                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
                        string folderpath1 = folderpath + "/";
                        fuDocpath.SaveAs(folderpath1 + filename);
                        lblName.Text = lblName.Text + "|" + filename;
                        lblerror.Text = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception eex)
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + eex.Message + "')", true);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblerror.Text = "File couldn't be uploaded." + ex.Message;
            lblName.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the total file size you want to upload?

Comment: anywhere between 10 to 15 MB . Iam actually creating a user based applications . So, clients will upload files of total maximum size 15 MB

Comment: your code works fine....i didn't get any single error.Can you provide us what actually u r doing when this error pops **OR** the steps to reproduce this issue

Comment: just try to upload anything larger than 5 MB and it won;t show popup alert

Comment: Could you use jquery??? It would be easy checking file size and showing pop alert in jquery

Comment: I don't know jquery ,otherwise I would have tagged it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this - [How to increase the max upload file size in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net)

You can change the max request size in web.config - the default is 4Mb

Comment: that's fine But what if I want to show popup alert it anything larger than is uploaded

Comment: The you'll need to use client-side validation. This could help - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/290098/Asp-Net-Custom-Validator-Control-to-validate-file - it's a custom validator for FileUpload controls that does basically what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're wondering about the nature of the error code/message thrown by the browser, [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/323246/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-web-server-in-asp.net-by-using-visual-c-.net) is a post that addresses it.
I'll quote a paragraph just in case of broken links in future:

> By default, ASP.NET only permits files that are 4,096 kilobytes (KB) (or 4 MB) or less to be uploaded to the Web server. To upload larger files, you must change the maxRequestLength parameter of the  section in the Web.config file.
>
> Note When the maxRequestLength attribute is set in the Machine.config file and then a request is posted (for example, a file upload) that exceeds the value of maxRequestLength, ***a custom error page cannot be displayed***. Instead, Microsoft Internet Explorer will display a "Cannot find server or DNS" error message.

The workaround is to modify the ***Machine.config*** file as explained in the answer given earlier by @sh1rts.