# maximum file size for asp.net FileUpload control

Tags: asp.net

What is the maximum file size allowed to upload to server using FileUpload control in asp.net ?

Is there any other better way to upload large files to server?

I get empty page if I upload file greater than 50MB.

I have added following in Web.Config

```
 <system.web>
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="180" />
 </system.web>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase the max upload file size in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net)

Comment: man, you should try googling your question :(

Comment: You can choose this yourself in your serverconfig

Comment: btw what made you choose 180 as your timeout?

Comment: It takes long time for calculation on file.