# Maximum size of file allowed using HTML input=file

Tags: html

Just curious.... Is there a maximum file size allowed when using html input? I read that the default in an asp mvc app is 4 mb, but is there an upper limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"maximum file size allowed" is not decided by html, but from the server code or web server settings.

please refer to this answer [max-upload-size-in-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net)