# Unable to upload Umbraco image larger than 4Mb

Tags: settings, umbraco, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7.2.1 and in the Media section uploading some images. I think Umbraco has limit for image size of 4Mb. When I try to upload images of greater size, they just simply come and disappear.

Umbraco should have a message or something to notify that size limit is crossed but thats a totally different issue.

My question is how this limit can be increased?

Comment: It's not an Umbraco limit, it's ASP.NET. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/288612/3668031

Comment: @JannikAnker : thanks Jannik... also found this --> http://24days.in/umbraco/2013/6-easy-configuration-tweaks/ stating the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to edit your web.config, maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength (the example is for 100mb uploads):

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="104857600" />
```

and also

```
<system.webServer>
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
   <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
```