# JQuery ajax with big data returns 404

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, ajax

I have ajax request that can have very long data (more than 2000 characters). I'm getting 404 from server. How can I solve this?

```
var data= { data: /*some long text*/'Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then she continued her way. On her way she met a copy. The copy warned the Little Blind Text, that where it came from it would have been rewritten a thousand times and everything that was left from its origin would be the word "and" and the Little Blind Text should turn around and return to its own, safe country. But nothing the copy said could convince her and so it didn’t take long until a few insidious Copy Writers ambushed her, made her drunk with Longe and Parole and dragged her into their agency, where they abused her for their projects again and again. And if she hasn’t been rewritten, then they are still using her. Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then she continued her way. On her way she met a copy. The copy warned the Little Blind Text, that where it came from it would have been rewritten a thousand times and everything that was left from its origin would be the word "and" and the Little Blind Text should turn around and return to its own, safe country. But nothing the copy said could convince her and so it didn’t take long until a few insidious Copy Writers ambushed her, made her drunk with Longe and Parole and dragged her into their agency, where they abused her for their projects again and again. And if she hasn’t been rewritten, then they are still using her. Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then she continued her way. On her way she met a copy. The copy warned the Little Blind Text, that where it came from it would have been rewritten a thousand times and everything that was left from its origin would be the word "and" and the Little Blind Text should turn around and return to its own, safe country. But nothing the co' }
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
  });
```

I have server method:

```
[HttpPost]
public dynamic PostText(string data)
{
            return data.Length;
}
```

I'm using MSSQLServer and IIS 8.5.9600

I've tried to set maxRequestLength as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net) but it didn't help

Maybe there is another way to send data? I can send it in "message-body" section. But I have no idea how to do it. I didn't find info about that. But I've tried to send it with [DHC](https://www.sprintapi.com/dhcs.html) and I could get data from body.

```
var s = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

So the question is how to add data to body in ajax?

Comment: Were you able to get an expected response for a lesser amount of data?

Comment: The server limits for post should be way higher than that, for example on PHP it's 8mb I think, edit: actually it's unlimited by default since 5.2.12

Comment: It usually depend on the server setting, in PHP it is `post_max_size`

Comment: Yes, I did. If I send less than 2000 characters

Comment: approx 2000 is the limit of a GET in some browsers, you need to say what server you are using and check your config - we can't know what limit it has been set to

Comment: Where can I set the limit in web.config?

Comment: Hitting a POST server limit wouldn't cause a 404 anyway. Or at least, it shouldn't. I'd be interested to see what the firebug console output is.

Comment: it returns: Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '.../post/PostText'."
MessageDetail: "No action was found on the controller 'Post' that matches the request."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What HTTP Server are you using?

Have you tried adding the following to your web.config?

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
<system.webServer>
```

This will bump up your allowed content length to a megabyte. Also, you may want to set the maxReceivedMessageSize attribute of your WCF bindings to more than the default 64k:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MessageSizeWeb" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
</webHttpBinding>
```

Also you might need to change the appSettings in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="400000" />
</appSettings>
```

You can also try:

1. Launch "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager"
2. Expand the Server field
3. Expand Sites
4. Select the site you want to make the modification for.
5. In the Features section, double click "Configuration Editor"
6. Under "Section" select: system.webServer>serverRuntime
7. Modify the "uploadReadAheadSize" section
8. Click Apply

Comment: What server are you using to host your application? You only told us your database server. Also I increased the deserialize value...

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's IIS 8.5.9600

Comment: Okay a new approach to try.

Comment: I've set 1149152 for uploadReadAheadSize but it didn't help