# OutOfMemoryException when send large file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, out-of-memory, download

In my asp.net project some files are located in the one of folders of the web site.
Direct links are provided for users to download that. It works fine until size of file not big (few Mb) but downloading file ~250Mb throws OutOfMemoryException.
There is no actions/code to manage this process. It is just direct link to file, something like css or js file in Content folder.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Is the server or client getting the out of memory exception? If it is the server, are you loading it into memory or opening a stream for the file on disk? You need to elaborate on what/where/how the problem is, otherwise "any idea how to fix it" can only be answered by "yeah, do it some other way". Post the code that throws the exception.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net