# Max File Size in roxy fileman

Tags: php, file, manpage, roxy-fileman

Is there any way to set the max file limit.
I already searched google and found this code (this code isnt working):

```
function addFile() {
clickFirstOnEnter('dlgAddFile');

var dialogButtons = {};
dialogButtons[t('Upload')] = function () {
var maxtotal = RoxyFilemanConf.MAXTOTAL;
var maxfilesize = RoxyFilemanConf.MAXFILESIZE;
var fileoversize = "";
var totalsize = 0;
if (!$('#fileUploads').val())
alert(t('E_SelectFiles'));
else {
if (!RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD) {
alert(t('E_ActionDisabled'));
//$('#dlgAddFile').dialog('close');
}
else {
var files = $('#fileUploads')[0].files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
//alert(files[i].name);
totalsize += files[i].size;
if ((files[i].size / 1024) > maxfilesize) {
fileoversize = files[i].name + '\n';
}
}

if ((totalsize / 1024 / 1024) > maxtotal) {
alert(t('E_MAXSIZE') + ". Set to " + maxsize + "MB.");
}
else if (fileoversize != "") {
alert("Max total upload : "+ maxfilesize +"KB. Oversized files:\n" + fileoversize);
}
else {
document.forms['addfile'].action = RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD;
document.forms['addfile'].submit();
}
}
}
};
dialogButtons[t('Cancel')] = function () { $('#dlgAddFile').dialog('close'); };

$('#dlgAddFile').dialog({ title: t('T_AddFile'), modal: true, buttons: dialogButtons });
}

Adding 2 variables to conf.json
MAXTOTAL and MAXFILESIZE.
```

but this doesnt work at all.. 
Anyone who got any suggestions/solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP has already discovered, this is a configuration setting which allows for files up to 4MB, but anything higher need some special changes.  For people searching for this solution in .Net, two changes are required in the web.config for IIS 7.0+. Check the link for more complete details.

I added the elements to my root web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <!-- Max int value of 2gb --> 
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" appRequestQueueLimit="100000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2097151" />    
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
     <security> 
        <requestFiltering> 
            <!-- maxAllowedContentLength, for IIS, in bytes --> 
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" ></requestLimits>
        </requestFiltering> 
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Sause:
[How to increase the max upload file size in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net)

I've also updated the code to work as intended with version 1.4.5. Make sure you apply this to the main.js/main.min.js files.

```
function addFile() {
    clickFirstOnEnter("dlgAddFile");
    $("#uploadResult").html("");
    clearFileField();
    var a = {};
    a[t("Upload")] = {
        id: "btnUpload",
        text: t("Upload"),
        disabled: true,
        click: function () {
            if (!$("#fileUploads").val() && (!uploadFileList || uploadFileList.length == 0)) {
                alert(t("E_SelectFiles"))
            } else {
                if (!RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD) {
                    alert(t("E_ActionDisabled"))
                } else {
                    // start of change
                    var maxtotal = RoxyFilemanConf.MAXTOTAL;
                    var maxfilesize = RoxyFilemanConf.MAXFILESIZE;
                    var fileoversize = "";
                    var totalsize = 0;
                    
                    for (var i = 0; i < uploadFileList.length; i++) {
                        totalsize += uploadFileList[i].size;
                        if ((uploadFileList[i].size / 1024) > maxfilesize) {
                            fileoversize = fileoversize + uploadFileList[i].name + '\n';
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if ((totalsize / 1024 / 1024) > maxtotal) {
                        alert(t('E_MAXSIZE') + ". Set to " + maxsize + "MB.");
                    } else if (fileoversize != "") {
                        alert("Max total upload : " + maxfilesize + "KB. Oversized files:\n" + fileoversize);

                    } else // end of change
                    if (window.FormData && window.XMLHttpRequest && window.FileList && uploadFileList && uploadFileList.length > 0) 
                    {
                        for (i = 0; i < uploadFileList.length; i++) {
                            fileUpload(uploadFileList[i], i)
                        }
                    } else {
                        document.forms.addfile.action = RoxyFilemanConf.UPLOAD;
                        document.forms.addfile.submit()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    a[t("Cancel")] = function () {
        $("#dlgAddFile").dialog("close")
    };
    $("#dlgAddFile").dialog({
        title: t("T_AddFile"),
        modal: true,
        buttons: a,
        width: 400
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This is fixed. I found out that the max file is going through the php.ini.

```
upload_max_filesize=4M
```