# Asp.Net/Azure Web App - File upload stopping when uploading to Azure Storage through Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm trying to upload an image to my Azure Blob Storage account through my ASP.NET web app hosted on Azure.

When I debugged the app locally and uploaded any file, the file would upload without any issue. However once i deployed my app to the Azure Web App service, my image upload would just stop at random percentages, 10%, 27&, 43% and so on.

If I use a file that's smaller than 100kB, it seems to work. But other image sizes ranging from 800kB, 1.3MB, 4MB just stop at random percentages. Why is occurring?

I was able to upload all files of the sizes listed above when I debugged my app locally on VS to the same Azure Storage container.

I don't think I need a chunked file upload approach since I'm not upload any large files, only images. But I need to be able to upload at least 2MB.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net

Comment: Have you got any errors or exceptions when the uploading process is not working?