# uploading a video to asp.net mvc 5 error: 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is the logic for the video upload. Please help me add buffering or whatever is needed to solve the error.

```
            if (video != null && video.contentLength > 0)
            {
                movie.Video = new byte[video.ContentLength];
                video.InputStream.Read(movie.Video, 0, video.ContentLength);
                var vidName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(video.FileName);
                movie.VideoFilePath = "../Uploads/movies/" + vidName;
                video.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/movies/"), vidName));

            }
            db.Movies.Add(movie);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        return View(movie);

    }
```

Comment: How big is the file you are trying to upload ?

Comment: I tried 100mb video, I can upload a picture with the same logic though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase the max upload file size in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net)

Comment: that only solves the 404.13 error but thank you for your input, I need help wiith adding buffering to my logic.

Comment: BTW, why are you saving in both disk and db ?

Comment: no reason, Is it wrong?