# asp.net core -"Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am working on a .net core project which has an web api to upload files. I have a middleware to check file's type, length etc.

I increased all limits on startup.cs file like this;

```
    services.Configure<FormOptions>(f =>
        {
            f.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue;
            f.ValueLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue;
            f.BufferBodyLengthLimit = Int64.MaxValue;
            f.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue;
            f.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue;
            f.MemoryBufferThreshold = Int32.MaxValue;
            f.ValueCountLimit = Int32.MaxValue;

        });
```

But somehow error still shows up.

I even tried to create attribute class for limits, but no luck.

Here is the middleware class where i am checking the files:

```
if (authToken != String.Empty)
        {

            var ctype = context.Request.ContentType;

            if (!IsMultipartContentType(context.Request.ContentType))
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unexpected error.");
            }

            var boundary = GetBoundary(context.Request.ContentType);
            var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, streamBody);
            reader.BodyLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue;
            var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
            while (section != null)
            {
                const int chunkSize = 256;
                var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
                var fileName = GetFileName(section.ContentDisposition);
                var bytesRead = 0;

                using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append))
                {
                    do
                    {

                        bytesRead = await section.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    } while (bytesRead < 0);
                }


                if (!verifyUpcomingFiles(buffer))
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Undefined file type detected.");
                }
                else
                {
                    //context.Request.Headers.Add("isVerified","verified");
                    await _next(context);
                     context.Request.ContentType = ctype;
            await _next(context);
                }


                section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
            }


        }
        else
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("You are not allowed to complete this process.");
            return;

        }
```

I have been trying to make this work for 2 days.

I almost give up. Any help any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try increasing the upload size using the `web.config` yet?[example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37475722/8579225)

Comment: I have no `web.config` file in the solution. @Drag0nvil

Comment: Might be related: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7019.