# HttpMaxlength exceeded

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have version 10. I am getting this exception.
I am trying to upload a mp3 file I have a lot of things in web.config but not getting solutions.

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded.]
       System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() +9906172
       System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent() +63
       System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +160
       System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm() +69
       System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +13
       System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_Form() +14
       System.Web.Mvc.HttpRequestExtensions.GetHttpMethodOverride(HttpRequestBase request) +121
       System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbsAttribute.IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo) +37
       System.Web.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute.IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo) +39
       System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorBase.IsValidMethodSelector(ReadOnlyCollection`1 attributes, ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo method) +54
       System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorBase.RunSelectionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 methodInfos) +118
       System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorBase.FindActionMethods(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +166
       System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorBase.FindActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +31
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.ReflectedAsyncControllerDescriptor.FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +54
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, String actionName) +203
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +136
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +465
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

Comment: Please check if this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net is the issue.

Comment: Yes It was thank you very much