# Uploading large file throwing 403 forbidden error

Tags: c#, iis

Hi I have a functionality in which we upload a large excel file. The code is working fine in local but after deploying the code on IIS when I try to upload the same file I get error :

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

If I upload small file its working perfectly fine. But when uploading large file it is throwing error. Any idea what can be the reason or any work around for the same.

Comment: You probably need to change the [maxRequestLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net) in your web.config file.

Comment: The maxRequestLength in local is same as IIS

Comment: So, in your IIS server, if you upload a small file it works. But if you upload a big file it doesn't work. Is that true?

Comment: Yes that's true.

Comment: Can you show your web.config file?

Comment: Wat exactly:   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="36000" enableVersionHeader="false" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxUrlLength="2048" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" maxQueryStringLength="1024" />

Comment: @AnirudhAgarwal Do you got any solution to this.... cause I am facing same issue and changing config parameters didn't helped... I think there is some setting missing in IIS... please revert if you know that can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Try this in your web.config file.***

```
 <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="####" />
      </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

"####"  is in KB.
default is 4000+ which is equal to 4mb.