# FileData is empty while uploading multipart media file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using **Postman** and my own **Restsharp based client** to send the audio file to the web API controller **when size exceeded from 3 or 4 MB provider.FileData showing contains 0 files**.

I also tried to use this but can't be solved the problem.
    **var provider = new MultipartFileStreamProvider(root);**

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile()
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
        if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        var task = await request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
            ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(o =>
                {
                    FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(provider.FileData.First().LocalFileName);
                    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    string fileName = guid + "_" + provider.FileData.First().Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName
                                          .Replace("\"", "");
                    File.Move(finfo.FullName, Path.Combine(root, fileName));

                    return new HttpResponseMessage()
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent("File uploaded.")
                    };
                }
            );

        return task;
    }
```

Comment: the max length is `4MB` you can increase file length in `web.config` file by `maxRequestLength`, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net

Comment: @Aria thanks i have solved it throught adding the **<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />** in system.web area of web.config file.