# Javascript how to pass the file path to API for conversion

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am developing a web application that enable users to upload wav file and convert it to mp3. So far I can convert wav to mp3 and save it to the project folder. What I can't find is pass the wav file to api dynamically.

```html
<div class="fileHolder">
  <b-form-file v-model="fields.file" accept=".wav" id="test"></b-form-file>
</div>
```

wav file to mp3 convert

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> test()
{
  string filename = null;
  if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

  string rootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads");
            var provider = new MultipartFileStreamProvider(rootPath);
   var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
                ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
                {
                    uploadResult r = new uploadResult();
                    if (t.IsCanceled || t.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, t.Exception);
                    }
                    foreach (MultipartFileData dataitem in provider.FileData)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Replace / from file name
                            string name = dataitem.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
                            filename = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1, name.Length);

                            //Create New file name using GUID to prevent duplicate file name
                            string newFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(name);
                            string mp3FileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".mp3";
                            //filename = newFileName;

                            //Move file from current location to target folder.
                            File.Move(dataitem.LocalFileName, Path.Combine(rootPath, newFileName));
                            //WavToMP3(Path.Combine(rootPath,newFileName), Path.Combine(rootPath,mp3FileName));
                            //File.Delete(Path.Combine(rootPath, newFileName));
                            r.fileName = mp3FileName;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            string message = ex.Message;
                        }
                    }
                    r.result = "Ok";
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, r);
                });

            return task;
}



public static void WavToMP3(string waveFileName, string mp3Filename, int bitRate = 128)
{
  CheckAddBinPath();
  using (var reader = new AudioFileReader(waveFileName))
  using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(mp3Filename, reader.WaveFormat, bitRate))
  reader.CopyTo(writer);
}
```

Javascript Code:

```
function onSubmit() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var file = this.fields.file;
    var fd = new FormData;
    fd.append("file", file);
    axios.post(`https://localhost:44324/api/G/test`, fd , {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then(r => {});
}
```

The new problem is when I upload 5mb file or higher `provider.Filedata` contains no data. But when the file is small there is data found on the `provider`
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is `<b-form-file>`? Post your Javascript code

Comment: I am using vue js btw. That is a bootstrap-vue component

Comment: What do you get on the network tab of your browser when you perform the request?

Comment: @CaddyDZ please refer to the updated code and question. The code works fine when I am trying to upload small file but when the file becomes 5mb or higher, `provider.Filedata` is empty

Comment: Must be a server configuration issue, the code isn't rejecting files based on size

Comment: @CaddyDZ what should I look for? can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/288675/5581565

Comment: @CaddyDZ that solve it. Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a JS problem but server setting preventing large files from being uploaded

So in your `web.config` of your ASP.NET or .NET Core

Change the default 4MB limit `4096` to 20MB for example

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Credits to [Eric Rosenberger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288675/5581565) SO answer