# 413 error on web application even with needed properties in web.config

Tags: c#, .net-4.7.2

I have a web application API which is published with IIS.

Clients upload files on my app (via PostMan) which I later process. It has been working fine. Now they tried to upload a large file of 70MB and they get 413 error.

I tried changing parts of web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="100000" />
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

But I still get the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: `I tried changing parts of web.config:` please show us what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, did you do [changes on config for increasing max upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net)? can you help us to provide an [mcve] so that we can try to help you further. cheers!

Comment: @SelimYıldız I wrote it in the original question but they weren't being shown because they weren't code formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem a while ago.

The fix is simply to up the size of the `UploadReadAheadSize` Metabase property.

IIS- uses a new Metabase property called `UploadReadAheadSize` when passing data to an ISAPI extension.

**How To:**

The following command instructs you to get the size as follows:

```
.cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/uploadreadaheadsize 204800
```

Comment: Yes. I changed that in my web.config file and still get 413.