# BizTalk to SharePoint: “The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request”

Tags: sharepoint, biztalk

I have a BizTalk 2013 orchestration receives an input file, processes it and in the end transfers it to a SharePoint 2010 folder.
It has been working OK earlier, with small (< 1 MB) files. But recently the orchestration has tried to upload a file of 230MB; and the orchestration failed (BizTalk put it to list of Suspended Items). The error was the following:

“ErrorCode 0xc0c0167a (Transmission Failure)
[System.Net.WebException] The remote server returned an error: (400) **Bad Request**.
This error was triggered by the Windows SharePoint Services receive location or send port with URI wss://intranetazure:80/OnlineParsing/Archive.
Windows SharePoint Services adapter event ID: 12310”.

The URI intranetazure:80/OnlineParsing/Archive is OK. I cannot understand – what went wrong? Could the root cause be the fact that the failed files are large (> 200 MB)?
What should I do to fix it?

Comment: As it is SharePoint that is throwing the error, you will have to check the error in SharePoint

Comment: Think this is related to the max file upload size. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net might help.