# ASP.NET file upload size restriction

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to restrict users from uploading file sizes of more than 4MB, is there any way to do this without modifying the configuration file? I tried the code below to validate the file and response redirect but was still not able to make it. As long as I upload a file that is larger than 4MB it crashes when I click submit.

```
if(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 1234)
{
    FileUpload1.Attributes.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase the max upload file size in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net)

Comment: nope, I was trying to not touch configuration file .