# Using Web API to download a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I took the Web API template and made slight change to working endpoint for the download.

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public FileStream Get()
{
    var path = @"C:\Users\user1\download.msi";
    return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
}
```

It's a 100mb download and I'm getting `Out of memory` when I trying download the file.

Comment: Memory limit? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18531025/7167572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output a file, you should use the [`File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-8.0) method:

```
var f = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
return File(f, "application/octet-stream");
```

If you return a FileStream, I guess ASP.NET will consider it as [special type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0), attempting to serialize the entire object before outputing it.