# "Error serializing or deserializing using JavaScriptSerializer JSON. The length of the string exceeds the value set in the maxJsonLength property."

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I need to send a JSON from JavaScript to a controller. The length of the JSON is 2199215.

I know that the maximum length of a JSON is 2097152, but I also know that this can be changed from the web.config. I tried changing it, but it still gives me the same error. For now I have split the request into more than one, so as not to exceed the maximum length, but I would prefer to do everything in a single request. Do you know why the MaxJsonLength I set in the web.config is not considered? Do you have any idea how to solve it? A thousand thanks.

This is the Ajax request I made

```
$.ajax({
        url: getUrl("Canali/RicalcolaRenderCanaliRows"),
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            canali: canaliInfo
        }),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (html) {
            // append the rendered rows to the channels' table
            $("#elencoCanali").find("tbody").append(html);
            // update info about the channels (e.g. the number of loaded channels)
            ricalcola_reloadInfo();
        },
        error: function (xhr, error) {
            showErrorMessage("Impossibile caricare i canali selezionati. Riprovare")
        },
        complete: function () {
            // riabilita i controlli sia in caso di successo che di errore
            ricalcola_enableControls();
        }
    });
```

And this is the Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult RicalcolaRenderCanaliRows(IEnumerable<CanaleDetailed> canali)
    {
        return PartialView(canali);
    }
```

Comment: Which JSON serialisation library are you using on the server side? If you're not using the default `JavaScriptSerializer`, then the MaxJsonLength won't be respected.

Comment: `I know that the maximum length of a JSON is 2097152,`,   To be clear that's not from Javascript end?  So showing Javascript code is really not much use.

Comment: Seen as this is a Server side issue, and you have updated the max size for JSON, you might also need to update the max size your receive via the POST request,.. I don't use ASP, but maybe this link might help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan On the server side I don't use a serialize, it simply converts the JSON into the CanaleDetailed class. I also uploaded the controller in the question, so it should be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the length when you return the json in the controller

```
var jsonResult = Json(myobject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
return jsonResult;
```